# changing div border radius makes part of border disappear

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to give one of my container divs rounded edges, using the border-radius property. However, when I do this, the textareas that are being rendered within the container div block the bottom left and right corners of the div. How can I adjust my css such that this no longer happens, and that the text areas work the way I want?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="screenDiv">
        <div className="topContainer">
          <div className="textContainer">
            <div className="textBoxes">
              <div className="leftTextBox">
                <textarea className="myText" />
              </div>
              <div className="rightTextBox">
                <textarea className="myText" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="languageDisplay">
              <div className="inputLanguage">
                <p>English</p>
              </div>
              <div className="outputLanguage">
                <p>Spanish</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.screenDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topContainer {
  height: 80%;
}

.botContainer {
  height: 20%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.topContainer,
.botContainer,
.textBoxes,
.languageDisplay {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.textBoxes {
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
}

.textContainer {
  width: 80%;
  height: 36%;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #161515;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

.languageDisplay {
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.inputLanguage {
  width: 5%;
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
}

.outputLanguage {
  width: 5%;
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  right: 20%;
}

.leftTextBox,
.rightTextBox {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
}

.myText {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code sandbox you could share?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-albattani-eqqyy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are adding a `border-radius` to your `<div />`, it is actually "curving in" on the space the div has which is causing the text area inside to overflow the container.

There are two ways I can see to deal with this. You could add a padding to the `textContainer` div:

```
padding: 1rem;
```

Or you could hide all overflow - meaning the inner text area would be hidden instead of being placed over the border of the `textContainer` div.:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This should keep the border intact.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide some padding to *.textContainer*, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add border-radius to your textboxes if you do not want to give padding to *.textContainer*